# Submanifolds of homogeneous spaces are homogeneous

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Is a submanifold of a homogeneous manifold is homogeneous? i.e $X=G/H$ for a Lie group $G$ and a closed subgroup $H$, then if $Y$ is a submanifold of $X$. Is there a subgroup $K$ of $G$ s.t $Y=K/(K\cap H)$?

Comment: Almost surely not..

Comment: Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Sure ... Take any random curve on a plane or sphere.